# printf() issue, showing a number at the end of my string? php

Tags: php

I am trying to use the printf() function to take two string variables and make a sentence phrase with them. the problem is i am getting a number at the end and i dont know why. here is what my code looks like

**php**

```
        <?php
            $string1 = "Hello";
            $string2 = "World";
            echo printf("%s %s", $string1, $string2);
            echo "<br>";
        ?>
```

this is my output:

*Hello World11*

where is the 11 coming from?

edit: I should probably note my variables are further up in my php script, as its used in some other sections of my code, but nothing alters the variables the just get called(echo) on to be displayed. just incase that might matter.

Comment: Remove the `echo` before the printf. Look into the manual what printf returns.

Comment: thank you and i will do some reading, issue solved. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Just next time try to play around with your current code a bit more. Like remove something (e.g. the `echo`) or so, just play around with your code.